# java.lang.NumberFormatException while executing in France machine

Tags: java, locale

In below code while parsing the value sometimes i am facing NumberFormat Exception in France machine.

```
double txPower;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

txPower = txPower + getDeltaP();
log.info("txpower value is -- "+txPower);
txPower = Double.parseDouble(df.format(txPower));


protected double getDeltaP() 
{
    return isNewChannelAddition ? apaConfig.deltaPadd : apaConfig.deltaPtune;
}
```

**logs:**

```
txpower value is -- -7.9
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-7,9"
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the decimal separator configured as default for your locale.

```
new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMA‌​T)).getDecimalSepara‌​tor();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ways to solve your problem :

One, you can use `replace(",", ".")` like this :

```
txPower = Double.parseDouble(df.format(txPower).replace(",", "."));
```

Two, you can use the local for the `DecimalFormat` :

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
df.applyLocalizedPattern("##.##");
txPower = txPower + getDeltaP();
txPower = Double.parseDouble(df.format(txPower));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also call something like this `String.format("%.2f", -7.9)`

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble` doesn't support locale-specific decimal points (see the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)).  Try using your `DecimalFormat` to parse instead:

```
txPower = df.parse(df.format(txPower)).doubleValue();
```

Having said that, I must ask what you are hoping to gain by to turning the `double` value `txPower` into a `String`,  parsing the string into a `double` and putting the result back into `txPower`?

Comment: i am just formatting the txpower value to DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##"), and assigning back  txPower.