# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "4,75"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my code I have a lot of testing and I have no crash. But when I have release my app to PlayStore a lot of crash appeared on this line

```
adjustedPrice =  "%.2f".format(price).toFloat()
```

I am testing manually trying to add some values as in crash but it seems not having the crash. If I am putting price as 4.75 it's okay.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason of this crash ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,75"
       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
       at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
```

Comment: your problem has to do with the locale at your machine, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541638/java-lang-numberformatexception-while-executing-in-france-machine)

Comment: Find differences between `4.75` and `4,75`. Check the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi decimal separator is not comma but dot (.)

You can replace comma with dot before parsing

```
val newPrice = price.replace(",", ".")
```

UPDATE: Also you can use custom symbols for parsing

```
fun parse(decimal: String): Number? {
    val symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols().apply {
        decimalSeparator = ','
        groupingSeparator = ' '
    }
    val df = DecimalFormat().apply {
        decimalFormatSymbols = symbols
    }
    
    return try {
         df.parse(decimal) ?: 0
     } catch (ex: ParseException){
         0
     }
}
```